# How do I setup the cert for my local IIS?

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate

I am not able to find the information for how to setup a cert for my local IIS.

Answer (score 0):

It depend on what kind of certificate do you want to apply.
If you only need to apply Self-signed certificate for testing purpose.

You could take following steps:

1. Go to IIS manager->server node->Server certificate

2.Create self-signed certificate->specify certificate friendly name->OK

3.Go to site node->bindings->Add..->select https and your self-signed certificate->OK

If you want to apply CA certificate for your trusted website.

Then you need to purchase certificate from CA authority like GlobalSign. They will provide your several certificates.

1.Double click these certificates to import them to certificate store.

2.Go to IIS manager->server node->server certificate->import..->import your certificate with .pfx extension. This is the certificate with private key

3.Go to site node->binding-> select your CA certificate in your https binding